# How To fix Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datetime, calendar

I want to insert all the data in the form to the database named Equipment.
However, when I click on the save button it shows error "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime."

I have set the data type for certain column in date time type. I put the calendar in the text box, so by clicking on the text box, it will pop up the calendar. The user can choose the date. The calendar that has been creating using javascript.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

[The form and the calendar pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/100Jp.png)

The code for save button:

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=5CG50749V3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {

        string sql = @"INSERT Into [Equipment]([OwnerID],[SubjecttoCal],[Model],[Option],[EquipmentID],[SerialNumber],[Description],[Location],
                            [DueDate],[EquipmentWithdraworRemarks],[NCRorOOTHistory],[LastOOTissuanceDate],
                            [AvailableinSapphire],[ResponsiblePerson],[CalibrationOption],[CalibrationSourceorLab],
                            [YearofManufacturing],[ManufacturerorVendor],[CalibrationCost],[AssetNo],[CalibrationTAT],[SendInDate],[Status])
                           ";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@OwnerID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@SubjecttoCal", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Model", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Option", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@EquipmentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox8.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@EquipmentWithdraworRemarks", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox10.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@NCRorOOTHistory", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox11.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@LastOOTissuanceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox12.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@AvailableinSapphire", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox13.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ResponsiblePerson", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox14.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@CalibrationOption", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox15.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@CalibrationSourceorLab", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox16.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@YearofManufacturing", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox17.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ManufacturerorVendor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox18.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@CalibrationCost", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox19.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@AssetNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox20.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@CalibrationTAT", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox21.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@SendInDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox22.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList2.Text;

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Your data have been saved')", true);



        }
    }
```

The javacript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=TextBox8]").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true
        });
        $("[id$=TextBox12]").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true
        });
        $("[id$=TextBox17]").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true
        });
        $("[id$=TextBox22]").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this looks like webform rather than MVC? You obviously assign a string to a datetime parameter. If knowing the date format before hand, just parse it first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your date string into datetime format. For eg:

```
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textboxValue, "MM/dd/yy", null);

//For eg
command.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox8.Text, "MM/dd/yy", null);
```

Btw, I am assuming `TextBox8.Text` return correct value from your datetime picker.

If it works then just do the same thing with other datetime textboxes

Comment: can you tell me where to put this code? Sorry I'm still new in asp.net.

Comment: the word textboxValue , do i need to replace it with TextBox.Text?

Comment: Yeah you should put the text box values there. Like `command.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox8.Text, "MM/dd/yy", null);` here I am putting `TextBox8.Text` value into Parse function

Comment: it still have error. it is related with the java sript that i use?

Comment: Yes, check the value of each datetime Textbox

Answer (score 0):

As looking at your code, you are taking date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format from the client side in textbox.
So you need to parse your date considering that format by following snippet.

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("22/3/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For your code you need to replace your "textbox.Text" with statement "DateTime.ParseExact(textbox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)" whereever you have mentiond data type DateTime.

i.e

```
        command.Parameters.Add("@DueDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox8.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        command.Parameters.Add("@LastOOTissuanceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox12.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        command.Parameters.Add("@SendInDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox22.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But why the cultureinfo text have red line?

Comment: might be you haven't added using  System.Globalization;

Comment: okay. but when i run it it show this error {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}. what this mean? @HemantDhake

Comment: can you please post here the value that you are getting from the TextBox8.Text, TextBox12.Text & TextBox22.Text by debugging.

Comment: where i need to do it? sorry my bad . @HematDhake

Comment: by simply putting debugger point at the start of your save method and get value from quickwatch

Comment: the value is  TextBox8.Text "22/04/2017" string. @HemantDhake